# Fully typed string in TS

Tags: typescript

I want the typescript to throw an error if the string contains a substring that is not a custom type key.

My code looks like this:

```js
type Dog = {
 id: string
 breed: string
} 

type Fields<T> = keyof T

// how to replace any ?
type StrWithFields = any

// good
const a: StrWithFields = 'id'
const b: StrWithFields = 'breed'
const c: StrWithFields = 'id breed'
const d: StrWithFields = 'breed id'

//bad
const e: StrWithFields = ''
const f: StrWithFields = 'id breed created_at'
```

How to replace `any` in my code?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcygXigbwFBQJYBMBcUAzsAE7YB2CWARqRBAcWZdQL5QYaiRQBi2CABtcRADwAVAHwooAawgg4AMygSuAeg1QAFnADuUYHCj0wQgIYBjaBYogoAfm7hoAZTIB1bMB0DhorJ2IJraCHBwuBhWcBQkUBaEHqTevv4iRLIA5HhZ0bHxNElePn6CGdl0DLh5MXHAUFbFKaXpgag5uFBVjLUFDUzJqWUBmR09XbmhNBZRdfEQzcNtY1BZffVQykut5e1reN30jI30FsCMAPrneUA)

Comment: Are you going to be using this type in a function?

Comment: What about duplicate fields?

Comment: How many keys will the real non-`Dog` type have?  That very much drives the solution, since if it's more than about five or six, it's going to be slow or impossible to represent `StrWithFields` as a specific type, and you'll have to resort to using a generic constraint like `VerifyStrWithFields<T>`.

Comment: Yes I wanna use this type in a function. Duplicate is prohibited

Comment: If you can provide 2 of these solutions, I will be glad. But of course more interested in the most universal type

Comment: [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL3oVN) shows the possibilities.  Which one of those should I write up in an answer? I *could* write up both but I'd probably go into less detail for each one.

Comment: I think second answer is good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific `StrWithFields` type that scales well with the number of keys.  Obviously if there are only two keys, say `"a"` and `"b"`, then you could easily represent it as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `"a" | "b" | "a b" | "b a"`.  But each additional key will make the union much bigger (e.g., `"a" | "b" | "c" | "a b" | "b a" | "a c" | "c a" | "b c" | "c b" | "a b c" | "a c b" | "b a c" | "b c a" | "c a b" | "c b a"`) and so as soon as you have a type with about seven or eight keys in it, you've exhausted TypeScript's ability to represent union types.

So instead of a *specific* type, we can write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `VerifyStrWithFields<T>` that takes a candiate string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `T` and produces an output such that `VerifyStrWithFields<T> extends T` if and only `T` would be a valid member of `StrWithFields`... and then we'd need a helper function so that developers don't have to manually specify the generic type parameter.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
type VerifyStrWithFields<T extends string> =
   VerifyConcatSpace<T, Fields<Dog>>

const asStrWithFields = <T extends string>(
  s: VerifyStrWithFields<T>
) => s;
```

where `VerifyConcatSpace<T, U>` checks that `T` is a valid concatenation of union members of `U`, as follows:

```
type VerifyConcatSpace<T extends string, U extends string, A extends string = never> =
   T extends U ? ConcatSpace<A, T> :
   T extends `${infer F extends U} ${infer R}` ?
   VerifyConcatSpace<R, Exclude<U, F>, ConcatSpace<A, F>> :
   A
```

This is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that TypeScript's compiler is able to compute with quite a large number of levels of recursion (up to ~1000).  The idea is that we keep track of intermediate results with an *accumulator* type parameter `A`, which starts of as `never`.  If `T` is a member of `U`, then we concatenate the current accumulator `A` with a space and `T`.  Otherwise if `T` starts with a member of `U` (call it `F`) followed by a space and the rest of the string (call it `R`), then we concatenate the current accumulator `A` with a space and `F`, and recurse by verifying `R` matches `U` with `F` removed from it (via [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)).

Oh and that `ConcatSpace<A, B>` is just a type that joins `A` and `B` with a space, unless `A` is `never`, in which case it just returns `B`:

```
type ConcatSpace<A extends string, B extends string> =
   [A] extends [never] ? B : `${A} ${B}`
```

---

Let's try it out:

```
const a = asStrWithFields('id'); // okay
const b = asStrWithFields('breed'); // okay
const c = asStrWithFields('id breed'); // okay
const d = asStrWithFields('breed id'); // okay

const e = asStrWithFields(''); // error!
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'never'.
const f = asStrWithFields('id breed created_at'); // error!
//Argument of type '"id breed created_at"' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type '"id breed"'.

const g = asStrWithFields("id id"); // error!
// Argument of type '"id id"' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type '"id"'.
```

Looks good. The compiler accepts the four strings you want to accept, but rejects others.  And let's make sure it works for types with a larger union:

```
type VerifyMyStr<T extends string> =
   VerifyConcatSpace<T,
      "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" |
      "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" |
      "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" |
      "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z">

const asMyStr = <T extends string>(
   s: VerifyMyStr<T>) => s;

asMyStr("a b c d e f"); // okay
asMyStr("z y x w v u t a b c d e f"); // okay
asMyStr("u n c o p y r i g h t a b l e"); // okay
asMyStr("u n f o r t u n a t e"); // error!
// Argument of type '"u n f o r t u n a t e"' is not
// assignable to parameter of type '"u n f o r t"'
```

Also looks good.  We could write some fairly long strings and the compiler is happy (which it wouldn't be if we needed to generate the union-of-all-possible-valid-strings).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcygXigbwFBWwSwCYBcUAzsAE44B2CW2ARmRBISeVTQL4YaiRQBiOCABs8xADwAVAHwooAawgg4AMyiTu3XtADCcSgGMAhsADKYIwYjiAglAgAPYBEpjWFagBooAIXtOXN1IPBFlkWigAbRsAXX9nV2IoyggANwgyOIB+XygiAAMAEjQbDihinw58rXBoADUMnBUQPUMTc0trSXjApOD2bwBVHsT3Aag7RwSgtmo5FPSyMIjuqd6oYZzW4zMLK1tvGTyVkbcitCoVDIFTpMGy4svrgCUqqCyIhopm7fa962e3gAog4DMIAK54ayDbz8aTeX67ToHATSWQECI2Gp8L5NECmcgAdRwwAAFoIRGIpLcxtRltgoLifvodh19pJYUJRBJ4KFpNwDPpSFAjMQCWRiWSKdy5NS1qN+nSABTEIhM-FEknkrlUmQAShQsmIAG5uAB6M1QBBwOB4DCCyjCoxyUXiyXaynEJUAcnw3r1xqgFqgcHkRhA9qFwCgdBdYs1Up1Xu9DCYeH9geDofDkcd0YMcbdWulYh9+BjjGYGaDluzEYdwrwhYTHu5PtTzCgfoDNZDYYjGAtdCMdob0egqFdLZLyerwYyZDgZAAhIPLTYyAhwQBbFzR1RQbRQb2KhDertJShwaOi4g4BCUIx0YTQNeHuBQCxkIy75xkENqEe3oLBk3oAHS5sKaiTvGErFkmZZNh2TYGIwJjMAA+iYc6WguS6rhaG5brulD7oBtTHgAROWyFQKhEDoXgWHAJR55vjgl7XiKxB3g+T4vu+n5GN+v7XAeQHUUhlZ4KxEGQdGSAwUWiaekqkldjJPbzmQi4rm+RE7nuAGHhR3rqfgrEXlAV7Rm+t73o+z7QMAH5fj+EB-sZEkWeBmg8BR6oALIamQcoBAqsyhCgnyNMybRIuyngRAylFGJRUAAD5QJRdDpVllEGHl2UyZl2UQEVlEqBVCB5cl2CUaSFU4BVABWFXyBVwgVduFWULVDIpXAFVgBVACOFVkBVxAVSxpWUeC-UDdlqQVQA7hVDgVSAFUAF6Ufy8nccF4qyqs4UzCE0hKhEqqMrFIDHeQUjSAayBGqaGCio9ZBqc6sYFk20BVVptb9p9xDfWpO1QCAUAOFAq1QKkUDgoeIoxnRUCA1AwOZqDOZfSFamo5QmOuTDUD-jgVpQKSaN-VAwj2JRIN9gTENE-N1k4yGlNoyT6PjizeP2Dp+H6ZuhmkV5plc6Tagfv+0YC86Qvnhx1nXnZPEOfxzmucJ7meeJssCwrfMsd6mhAA)